# How to resolve the css clash of mapcontrol terrain

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am getting scroll on terrain when i hover on MAP. I tried this code but it didn't fix that.

I already did `<i>overflow:hidden` and `<i>max-width:none;` This is not affecting the map. 
Check the screen shot:

Already tried this code:

```
    #myDivi {overflow: hidden;width:auto;
height:auto;}
img {
  max-width:none;

}#mapCanvas img {
  max-width: none;overflow: hidden;
}
.gmnoprint img { max-width: none; }
.gmnoprint label {  width: auto; display: inline; overflow:hidden;height:auto;  }
.gm-style img { max-width: none; overflow:hidden; width:auto; height:auto;}
.gm-style label { width: auto;  overflow:hidden;height:auto; }
```